# How to build a messaging system in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, messaging

I'd like to write a program where you can have 2 clients that talk to each other in realtime. I've been looking into WCF services and Duplex messaging, data contracts etc but now I'm confused.

Basically I see it as:

[Client] --- msg --> [Server] --- msg --> [Client] and vica versa.

The server will just act as the messenger.

Could you please point me in the right direction? I'd like to use WPF for the client apps.

Comment: If this is still relevant, then I would suggest SignalR (as of Jan. 2020). Maybe Blazor Server side would be relevant for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [WCF peer-to-peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) programming paradigm. It will be extended in WCF 4 (with .NET 4 - due out April 12, 2010) by allowing dynamic [discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782%28VS.100%29.aspx) (and [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335779.aspx)) of other clients on your network.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the dynamic discovery and ran the solution in VS. I'm still stuck.

It feels like there's a handful of different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

This should help get you going: [WCF / WPF Chat Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWPFChat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Windows Azure Service Bus](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) (which uses WCF) might be worth a look?

Service bus can effectively be used as a message bus, which is one way to implement what you are describing.

Comment: Not necessarily. I believe you can use it locally, and samples ive seen are not much more complex than straight wcf

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two scenarios

1. The clients are the only ones that start a request, to send they push messages and to receive they request periodically for new messages. The main advantage of this architecture is that it is more firewall-proof.
2. The clients are also servers that receive messages relayed by the central server. The main advantage is that the clients receive updates faster and they save bandwidth.

Comment: I'm interested in option 2 but am unsure of what to look at with WPF/WCF

Answer (score -1):

I wrote program like your sample!!! 
but it has one big different: My program have a chat server and a client. clients can chat to others.(with chat server service)

This program use **two wcf service** for make a connection between client and server.(client call server and send message for it,server get message from client and send for all client have connected to server)I think u used one service and must be use two service(like me) or use **Duplex Service**.

The sucha barber`s example is too cool(WCF/WPF Chat Application in answer eric). He used duplex services but real problem of this example is "sucah used WPF too and it s expert example for beginners (like me and u)".

If u want i can share my program!!!

[seethis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761779/wcf-services-peoblem2-way-connection)